# Developing .NET Forms applications in OSX using gtk#

Tags: .net, macos, user-interface, gtk#

First off, is it possible to develop native looking .NET GUI applications for OSX Lion? When I tried to run one of my Windows Forms applications using Mono in OSX, it was not having the native OSX look and feel. I came across gtk# recently. Has anybody tried it? Is there any open source GUI applications developed on Mono for OSX so that I can have a look before dwelling into gtk#?

Comment: The GTK# Stack on OSX is right now heavily being improved by Xamarin. Most things do work even now.

Comment: GTK doesn't have a native OSX look and feel... at least not yet.

Comment: I don't think GTK will ever have a native look and feel. That's the point it's consistency across platforms.  Also the GTK layout engine works completely different than OS X and Windows native layout engines.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac)